# SqLite. Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть таблица:

```
create_table_quant = """CREATE TABLE Quantity (Name VARCHAR NULL DEFAULT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  Quan INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,  Type_mes_q INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL);"""
```

Хочу заполнить таблицу значениями

```
def insert_quant(Name_f, Type_mes):
        sqlite_insert_quant = '''   INSERT INTO Quantity
                    (Name,Type_mes_q)
                    VALUES (?,?);
                    '''
        data = (Name_f,Type_mes)
        cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_quant, data)
```

Сама функция вызывается так :

```
        for i in range(7):
            insert_quant([pr_text[i]], i)
```

Вылезает ошибка:

```
Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type
```

Pr_text это массив, поэтому я заключил его в [], иначе вылезает ошибка

```
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 51 supplied.
```

Как я понимаю проблема с i,менял на int(i), тип type_mes_q в таблице на varchar и на text, заключал i в []. Ничего не помогло

Comment: я в таком случае делаю минимальный скрипт, чтобы его запустить можно было, и помещаю тут. А куски кода - только для умозрительного анализа.

Comment: В текущем виде точно неправильно. в Name_f нужно передавать строку, а вы передаете список. Что у вас за объекты в pr_text?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA
В pr_text[i] <class 'str'>, заменил [pr_text[i]] на кортеж (pr_text[i],) ошибка остается:
Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type
Если запускать без любых скобок вылезает ошибка:
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 51 supplied

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было заменить `data = (Name_f,Type_mes)` на `data_q = (str(Name_f), Type_mes_q)`